# log4j2 error The method getParent() is undefined for the type Logger

Tags: log4j, log4j2

we are in the process of migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j2 for java application. We are using the below code
logger.getParent() and have log4j2 jar files.
However, we are getting the below error.

The method getParent() is undefined for the type Logger.

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to fix this.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you are talking about?